# How to CD inside a SFTP connection where the connection is established using - Shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sftp

In my script - i create a sftp connection.

I read some directory value from user earlier and once the sftp connection is established, i try to cd to that dir which i got from the user.

But its not working, probably bec the prompt goes inside the server to which the SFTP connection was established.

In this case how to make it work ?

Comment: SFTP protocol has no concept of "current directory", consequently you can't "cd" anywhere. Console SFTP clients emulate chdir-like commands internally.

Answer (score 6):

I also faced this problem and was able to find the solution. The solution is right there in the man page of sftp. In the man page, you will find where it is written the format of using sftp like this:

```
sftp [options] [user@]host[:dir[/]]
```

Actually, two formats are given there but this is the one I wanted to use and it worked.

So, what do you do? You simply supply the `username@host` as seen there, then, without any space followed by `:` and the path you want to change to in the client/remote server in your script and that's all. Here is a practical example:

```
sftp user@host:/path/
```

Answer (score 2):

If your script does, as you state somewhere in this page,

```
sftp $user@$host cd $directory
```

and then tries to do something else, like:

```
sftp $user@$host FOO
```

That command `FOO` will *not* be executed in the same directory `$directory` since you're executing a new command, which will create a new connection to the SFTP server.

What you can do is use the "batchfile" option of sftp, i.e. construct a *file* which contains all the commands you'd like sftp to do over one connection, for example:

```
$ cat commands.txt
cd foo/bar
put foo.tgz
lcd /tmp/
get foo.tgz
```

Then, you will be able to tell sftp to execute those commands in one connection, by executing:

```
sftp -b commands.txt $user@$host
```

So, I propose your solution to be:

- With user's input, create a temporary text file which contains all the commands to be executed over one SFTP connection, then
- Execute sftp using that temporary text file as "batch file"

Your script would do something like:

```
echo "Directory in which to go:"
read directory
temp=$( mktemp /tmp/FOOXXX )
echo "" > $temp
echo "cd $directory" >> $temp
# other commands
sftp -b $temp $user@$host
rm $temp
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change the directory of the machine, try lcd

Comment: If this is the part of my script                                 sftp $uid@$ip                                                     cd $path                                                               - once the sftp command gets executed, the prompt goes to the server on which the sftp command was executed. So it is not executing the cd/lcd command present in the next line fo the script

Answer (score -2):

In what way is it not working?  To change directories on the remote server, you use the "cd" command.  To change directories on the local server, you use the "lcd" command.  Read "man sftp".

Comment: If this is the part of my script sftp $uid@$ip cd $path - once the sftp command gets executed, the prompt goes to the server on which the sftp command was executed. So it is not executing the cd/lcd command present in the next line fo the script